# To be allowed to do x y z

Tags: grammar

Good morning,
My first post here - I would like to say "we are allowed to do exercise outside" - I had a go, is it correct? そとたいぞおうをゆるされる - or do I need  します　in there too? 
What is the structure grammatically for "be allowed to + verb"? 
Many thanks in advance,
RA

Comment: `たいぞおう` -- Can you double check that's what you meant to type.

Answer (score 2):

> そとたいぞおうをゆるされる - or do I need  します　in there too?

This should be something like

そと**での**たいそう**が**ゆるされる

"taiso" usually means some kind of callisthenics, normally うんどう will mean exercise in general.

そとでの　**うんどう**が　ゆるされる

> What is the structure grammatically for "be allowed to + verb"?

ゆるされる makes it sound like you are under someone's control, so you can use for example してもいい

そとで　うんどう　**しても　いい**

Comment: thank you both, sorry I forgot to say I don't read much kanji, but basically if I try the construction with a verb it would be , for instance, くすりがかいにいくゆるされる ? something tells me it's not correct ....

Comment: @user38405 I'd say it as 「[薬]{くすり} **を** [買]{か}いに[行]{い}く**こと**が[許]{ゆる}されている。」「薬**を**買いに行く**こと**を許されている。」 (を is the object marker. こと is a nominaliser.) or 「薬を買いに行くことができる。」( *lit.* "(We) are able to go to buy medicines.") or maybe 「薬を買いに行ってもいい。」

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, if you want to state that you got *explicit permission* from someone (for example a teacher) to do something,  I think that the causative form could be used. According to this definition (emphasis mine, source [here](https://kawakawalearningstudio.com/all/how-to-make-and-use-japanese-causative-form/)):

> Japanese Causative Form is a set of conjugation patterns used to describe either making/causing a person (or animal) to do something, or **letting a person (or animal) do something**.

Applied to your sentence, it would read:

> [先生{せんせい}は私{わたし}に]外{そと}で運動{うんどう}させます。The teacher makes me do exercise outside / The teacher allows me to do exercise outside.

Note that using the causative verb along with くれる makes it clear that the teacher is *allowing* me to do exercise outside, rather than *having* me to do exercise. I.e., it marks that the causative is used with the meaning"let someone do" rather than "make/cause someone to do":

> [先生{せんせい}は私{わたし}に]外{そと}で運動{うんどう}させてくれます。
>   The teacher allows me to do exercise outside.

Answer (score 0):

> "We are allowed to do exercise outside."

You could say:

> 「[外]{そと}で[運動]{うんどう}することが[許]{ゆる}されています。」
>   「外で運動することを許されています。」

こと is a nominaliser and turns the verb 運動する into the noun form so that it can be followed by the case particle が or を.

<sub>(許され**ている** expresses the *state* of being permitted. 許される would sound more like an action or event of being permitted.)</sub>

or:

> 「外で運動できます。」 *Lit.* (We) are able to exercise outside.

or, as @Ben suggested:

> 「外で運動してもいいです。」 *Lit.* It's okay if (we) exercise outside. → (We) may exercise outside.